# Extract only the title of an article from a TXT file in Python

Tags: python, text, extract

I would appreciate your guidance in the following problem. I need to bulk extract only the articles titles from a series of publications. The idea is that I receive the files in PDF, I extract only the first page (done), bulk convert to TXT (done), and I am stuck in the last phase.

The structure of the TXTs is as follows:

--- JOURNAL of MEDICINE and LIFE

JML | REVIEW

**The role of novel poly (ADP-ribose) inhibitors in the treatment of locally advanced and metastatic Her-2/neu negative breast cancer with inherited germline BRCA1/2 mutations.
A review of  the literature**

Authors list, etc, etc ---

In need only the title (in bold), from each file. I can do the iteration, that is not a problem.

With the code below I tried to identify paragraph 1:

```
    data = file.read()
    array1 = []
    sp = data.split("\n\n")
    for number, paragraph in enumerate(sp, 1):
        if number == 1:
            array1 += [paragraph]
            print (array1)
```

No results whatsoever...

The idea is that I need to save only the titles in a file (could be TXT) as I need this list for another purpose.

Many thanks!

Comment: What is actually in `sp`?

Comment: I tried to split in lines...not sure if it's ok though

Comment: If tittle is always going to be 3rd line then just use `sp[2]`

Comment: @Ashish -  I did that. Got no error, but also no return. Just blank. The code is now: ```for files in os.listdir():
    data = file.read()
    array1 = []
    sp = data.split("\n\n")
    for number, paragraph in enumerate(sp, 2):
        if number == 1:
            array1 += [paragraph]
            print (array1)```

Comment: You can read the file, split on 2 newlines and then take the 3rd item from the list `for file in os.listdir():
    data = open(file, "r")
    sp = data.read().split("\n\n")
    print(sp[2])` Or is there more specific logic to it like getting all the text between this string format `JML | REVIEW` and this string format `Authors list, etc, etc ---` ?

Comment: What. Is. Actually. In. `sp`?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yes, there will be more logic into it if I could just get everything between JML and Authors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might read the whole file using  `.read()` and use a pattern with a capture group to match from JML to Authors.

```
^JML\s*\|.*\s*\r?\n((?:.*\r?\n)*?)Authors\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `JML\s*\|` match JML, optional whitespace chars and `|`
- `.*\s*\r?\n` Match the rest of the line, optional whitespace chars and a newline
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `(?:.*\r?\n)*?` Match all lines as least as possible
- `)` Close group 1
- `Authors\b` Authors

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u6S5ez/1)

For example:

```
import os
import re

pattern = r"^JML\s*\|.*\s*\r?\n((?:.*\r?\n)*?)Authors\b"
array1 = []

for file in os.listdir():
    with open(file, "r") as data:
        array1 = array1 + re.findall(pattern, data.read(), re.MULTILINE)
print(array1)
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for the excellent and detailed explanation. I have tried the code, no error whatsoever, but the output is a blank array "[]", as seen here https://ibb.co/fpmKf8B

Comment: @OviSele you can prepend the path to the file before the `file` in this part `with open(file` because when you do `print(file)` in the loop you only see the name of the file.

Comment: Thank you! Like I did below? I get the same result [] ```for file in os.listdir():
    with open('C:\\Users\\OviSele\\Downloads\\Test\\testpy.txt', "r") as data:
        array1 = array1 + re.findall(pattern, data.read(), re.MULTILINE)
print(array1)```

Comment: @OviSele You use [listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) which will `Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by path` Then, for every name that you get, you have to open that file in the right path :-) So the I think in your case perhaps `import os
import re

pattern = r"^JML\s*\|.*\s*\r?\n((?:.*\r?\n)*?)Authors\b"
array1 = []
path = "C:\\Users\\OviSele\\Downloads\\Test\\"
for file in os.listdir(path):
    with open(path + file, "r") as data:
        array1 = array1 + re.findall(pattern, data.read(), re.MULTILINE)
print(array1)`

Comment: of course, you are totally correct about listdir. My bad! Tried your version, which looks absolutely correct, still no result, only []. Please see here - https://ibb.co/3dnBj2v

Comment: @OviSele I created a file with the exact contents on my machine (Ubuntu) and for me it works. Can you `print(data.read())` right after this line `with open(path + file, "r") as data:`  to check if there is a result? And if there is a result, can you add that to this link https://regex101.com/r/u6S5ez/1 to see if there is a match? In the regex101 link, you can paste the result, and then at the left top save the regex and paste back the link here.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Print(data.read()) returns the content of the document. It seems that is working just fine. Please see here https://ibb.co/FBY7cjF   Will be back with the regex soon.

Comment: It's working. The problem was that in my example there was only one Author, and the first file there were many Authors. The last "s" was giving us all the pain. Please see here - https://ibb.co/Ptt7Km9 One last question - how can we stop parsing before authors? I only need the article name. Many many thanks again!

Comment: @OviSele re.findall will return the value in the capture group (The in green highlighted part in the regex101 link) You could stop the match before Author(s) like this https://regex101.com/r/bTec7j/1 for example, or like this if Authors does not have to be present https://regex101.com/r/6DYveI/1

Comment: Excellent! Very very much appreciated!  Thanks a million!